# Unable To Plot Graph From PostgreSQL Query Results In Dash App

Tags: postgresql, heroku, plotly-dash

I am attempting to write a simple code to simply plot a bar graph of some fruit names in the x-axis vs corresponding sales units. The aim of this code is just to understand how to query postgres results from heroku hosted database through a dash app.

Below is the code,

```
from dash import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import psycopg2
import os

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT fruits FROM pgrt_table")
fruits1=cur.fetchall()
#print(fruits1)
cur.execute("SELECT sales FROM pgrt_table")
sales1=cur.fetchall()


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(
        children='Hello Dash'
    ),

    html.Div(
        children='''Dash: A web application framework for Python.'''
    ),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
       figure=go.Figure(
            data=[
                go.Bar(
                x=fruits1, y=sales1, name='SF'),
                #{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],

            #'layout':{
            #    'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            #}
        )
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The output is below,

[Output to the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlRDg.jpg)

The corresponding output is just the axes with no bar graphs. The connection with the db is working since printing fruits1 or sales1 gives me the values from the columns in postgres. The only issue is the plotting.

NOTE: This question has been heavily modified since the previous draft was extremely vague without any code to show for.

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: Hey, Nils I have modified the question to be more specific.

Comment: x='fruits1', y='sales1' - why are you trying to set strings as data? Try to remove the `'`

Comment: Just tried it. No luck, just the numbered axes.

Comment: What exacly is the output of `print(fruits1)`?

Comment: Is it a dictionary?

Comment: [('apple',), ('banana',), ('mango',), ('pineapple',), ('peach',), ('watermelon',)] is the output, the names of the fruits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
fruits1 = [('apple',), ('banana',),
           ('mango',), ('pineapple',),
           ('peach',), ('watermelon',)]
```

The output of your database cannot be used directly:

```
xData = [fruit[0] for fruit in fruits1]
# gives ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'pineapple', 'peach', 'watermelon']
yData = [sales[0] for sales in sales1]
```

You have to assign your data to the `go.Bar` object:

```
go.Bar(x=xData, y=yData, name='SF')
```

Comment: Just a quick question, xData = [fruit[0] for fruit in fruits1] does this work as a loop or something to pull and store the individual values in fruits1 into xData ?

Comment: It is basically a loop in a short form. It iterates over each element in `fruits1` and returns the value with index 0. Its also called List comprehension. You can find more informations for e.g. on http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/python-single-line-loops